# mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: mysql

Could someone please tell me why I am getting this error and what I should change!

> mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER     int,\n
>   FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES papers(ID),\n        PRIMARY K' at line
>   4")

This is my statement:

```
""" CREATE TABLE Authors (
    ID        int NOT NULL,
    AUTHOR   varchar(255),
    ORDER     int,
    FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES papers(ID),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, ORDER)
    ) """
```

Thank you I am new to sql and simply cannot spot where I have gone wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"ORDER" is a reserved word and cannot be used as a field name...

```
Select * from Author order by order;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

If you absolutely want to use order as a field name, you must quote it, but it is better to avoid it, since you also would need to quote it in any sql sentence refering it.

Comment: Glad I could help. please marked the answer as accepted (which also will give you some extra so-points)